# How to pass a variable from JavaScript to HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JavaScript defined in my file as follows:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var transports = "<%=api.transports%>";
    var httpsTransport;
    var httpTransport;
    var splittedTransports= transports.split(',');
    for(i = 0; i < splittedTransports.length; i++)
    {
        if(splittedTransports[i]=="https") {
            httpsTransport="https";
        } else if (splittedTransports[i]=="http") {
            httpTransport="http";
        }
    }
</script>
```

And I would like to read it in my HTML page like:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox inline">
        <input type="checkbox"  id="transport_http" name="transport_http"  value="http" <%if(httpTransport=="http"){%>checked<%}%> />
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="transport_https" name="transport_https"  value="https" <%if(httpsTransport=="https"){%>checked<%}%>/>
    </label>
</div>
```

But now I get an error that states:

```
org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "httpTransport" is not defined.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I want to allow user to select an checkbox and save the form, and when he tries to edit the form, I want to show what he has saved in his previous operation.
So, when he tries to edit I try to read the values form backend and would like to show that particular option as checked.

Comment: why not just check and uncheck checkbox using javascript?

Comment: I suugest you to try data-attributes in html5.

Comment: make sure the `<script>` is above the `HTML`. It seems it simply is not defined, i.e. while trying to establish `un/checked` the JS value is not yet existing (for example, because the HTML is above JS in the source)

Comment: @MohitArora yes that is waht im doing, i can do first operation that waht user selects, now when he tries to edit form, i need to show what he did earlier, That is place im stuck here.

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai no it is above to html tags..:(

Comment: Is that page is jsp?

Comment: @Ratha do not overcomplicate the task. Take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bf5kvhp8/) to see how it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript">
var transports = "<%=api.transports%>";
var splittedTransports= transports.split(',');
for(i = 0; i < splittedTransports.length; i++)
{
if(splittedTransports[i]=="https"){
   document.getElementById("transport_https").checked = true;
}else if (splittedTransports[i]=="http"){
   document.getElementById("transport_http").checked = true;
}
}

</script>
```

HTML :

```
<div class="checkbox">
       <label  class="checkbox inline " >
           <input type="checkbox"  id="transport_http" name="transport_http"  value="http" />
       </label>
       <label  class="checkbox inline" >
           <input type="checkbox" id="transport_https" name="transport_https"  value="https"/>
       </label>
</div>
```

Comment: `if-else-if` can be simplified into `if (splittedTransports[i] == "https" || splittedTransports[i] == "http") { document.getElementById("transport_" + splittedTransports[i]).checked = true; }`

Answer (score 1):

The variables in your code are **declared**, but **not** **defined**.
Give them a random value first, and then update it with the `if`

```
<script language="javascript">
 var transports = "<%=api.transports%>";
    var httpsTransport = 'no';
    var httpTransport = 'no';
    var splittedTransports= transports.split(',');
    for(i = 0; i < splittedTransports.length; i++)
    {
    if(splittedTransports[i]=="https"){
        httpsTransport="https";
    }else if (splittedTransports[i]=="http"){
        httpTransport="http";
    }
    }

</script>
```